# How to export a class in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so im trying to export some classes from my musicplayer file, playlist, setMusicIndex and currentMusicIndex

```
const playlist = [
  {name: 'September', src: september, duration: '3:47'},
  {name: 'hello again', src: hello, duration: '04:19'},
]

const MusicPlayer = () => {
  const [currentMusicIndex, setMusicIndex] = useState(0)
  function handleClickPrevious() {
    setMusicIndex(currentMusicIndex === 0 ? playlist.length - 1 : currentMusicIndex - 1)
  }
  function handleClickNext() {
    setMusicIndex(currentMusicIndex < playlist.length - 1 ? currentMusicIndex + 1 : 0)
  }
  return (
    <AudioPlayer
      autoPlay={true}
      showSkipControls={true}
      showJumpControls={false}
      volume="0.2"
      onClickPrevious={handleClickPrevious}
      onClickNext={handleClickNext}
      onEnded={handleClickNext}
      src={playlist[currentMusicIndex].src}
    />
  )
}

export default MusicPlayer;
```

then i want to import those into my music file to make a playlist,

```
class Music extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div className="music-playlist">
                    <ul>
                        {playlist.map((song, i) => (
                            <li
                                role="menuitem"
                                tabIndex={0}
                                onClick={() => setMusicIndex(i)}
                                onKeyPress={() => { }}
                                key={i}
                                className={`${currentMusicIndex === i && 'playing'}`}>
                                {currentMusicIndex === i && <i className="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>}&nbsp;{song.name}
                                <div className="song-duration">{song.duration}</div>
                            </li>
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Music;
```

i did read up on exports since im new to js and react,  and i tried

```
export default MusicPlayer, playlist, setMusicIndex, currentMusicIndex;

import MusicPlayer, {playlist, setMusicIndex, currentMusicIndex } from '../../Components/MusicPlayer/MusicPlayer'

import { playlist, setMusicIndex, currentMusicIndex } from '../../Components/MusicPlayer/MusicPlayer'

import * from '../../Components/MusicPlayer/MusicPlayer'
```

and im still getting error saying

```
Attempted import error: 'playlist' is not exported from '../../Components/MusicPlayer/MusicPlayer'.
```

anyone willing to export those for me

Comment: You can only have one default export. Imports inside curly braces are for named exports, not default exports see https://medium.com/@etherealm/named-export-vs-default-export-in-es6-affb483a0910

Comment: ok,  so  how would i import these into my music file  
./src/Pages/Music/Music.js

  Line 10:26:  'playlist' is not defined           no-undef
  Line 14:48:  'setMusicIndex' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 17:47:  'currentMusicIndex' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 18:34:  'currentMusicIndex' is not defined  no-undef

@Tim

Comment: file1: `export const playlist = [...`, file2: `import { playlist } from 'path/to/file1'`

Comment: You've confused several different react concepts and ended up with things in the wrong place, I'd either learn a bit more about js first or take up an offer like @aamirl's to guide you through the process

Comment: thx for the help Tim  :) 
@aamirl if u dont mind that would be great,.  if u have discord we can talk there, name is csx#2453.  tried looking for a messaging here but not sure if there is one

Comment: @aamirl how do i enable my mic (no webcam) on the site, using firefox

Comment: @aamirl sorry,  im not finding that enable thing,  or its not giving me a option to enable it

Answer (score 0):

In your case these 3 are not classes, playlist is an array, currentMusicIndex is an integer and setMusicIndex is a function, and the three are not exported so you can't import them in another component like this.

you can:

1. Create a parent container that contains both MusicPlayer and Music, and set the playlist, currentMusicIndex and setMusicIndex in this `<ParentContainer />`, then pass them as props to its MusicPlayer and Music children
2. Use [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/)
3. Use [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Answer (score 0):

you are only declaring playlist variable but not exporting it. Just add the keyword `export` for your variable so it becomes a named export:

```
export const playlist = [
  {name: 'September', src: september, duration: '3:47'},
  {name: 'hello again', src: hello, duration: '04:19'},
]
```

then you can just import that using named import:

```
import {playlist} from ''path/to/your/jsFile'
```